# Android Split GPS tracking file from MainActivity.java

Tags: java, android, gps

I can't figure out how I can split this one into 2 files. I'd like to have one file **GPSTracking.java** to call when I need it from **MainActivity.java**.

This is the file I have to split

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements LocationListener {


final String TAG = "GPS";
private final static int ALL_PERMISSIONS_RESULT = 101;
private static final long MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 10;
private static final long MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES = 1000 * 60;

TextView tvLatitude, tvLongitude;
LocationManager locationManager;
Location loc;
ArrayList<String> permissions = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<String> permissionsToRequest;
ArrayList<String> permissionsRejected = new ArrayList<>();
boolean isGPS = false;
boolean isNetwork = false;
boolean canGetLocation = true;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    tvLatitude = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvLatitude);
    tvLongitude = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvLongitude);

    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Service.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    isGPS = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    isNetwork = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
    permissionsToRequest = findUnAskedPermissions(permissions);

    if (!isGPS && !isNetwork) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Connection off");
        showSettingsAlert();
        getLastLocation();
    } else {
        Log.d(TAG, "Connection on");
        // check permissions
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            if (permissionsToRequest.size() > 0) {
                requestPermissions(permissionsToRequest.toArray(new String[permissionsToRequest.size()]),
                        ALL_PERMISSIONS_RESULT);
                Log.d(TAG, "Permission requests");
                canGetLocation = false;
            }
        }

        // get location
        getLocation();
    }
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onLocationChanged");
    updateUI(location);
}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle bundle) {
}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {
    getLocation();
}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {
    if (locationManager != null) {
        locationManager.removeUpdates(this);
    }
}

private void getLocation() {
    try {
        if (canGetLocation) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Can get location");
            if (isGPS) {
                // from GPS
                Log.d(TAG, "GPS on");
                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                        LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                        MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                        MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);

                if (locationManager != null) {
                    loc = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                    if (loc != null)
                        updateUI(loc);
                }
            } else if (isNetwork) {
                // from Network Provider
                Log.d(TAG, "NETWORK_PROVIDER on");
                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                        LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,
                        MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                        MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);

                if (locationManager != null) {
                    loc = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                    if (loc != null)
                        updateUI(loc);
                }
            } else {
                loc.setLatitude(0);
                loc.setLongitude(0);
                updateUI(loc);
            }
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "Can't get location");
        }
    } catch (SecurityException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private void getLastLocation() {
    try {
        Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
        String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false);
        Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
        Log.d(TAG, provider);
        Log.d(TAG, location == null ? "NO LastLocation" : location.toString());
    } catch (SecurityException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private ArrayList findUnAskedPermissions(ArrayList<String> wanted) {
    ArrayList result = new ArrayList();

    for (String perm : wanted) {
        if (!hasPermission(perm)) {
            result.add(perm);
        }
    }

    return result;
}

private boolean hasPermission(String permission) {
    if (canAskPermission()) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            return (checkSelfPermission(permission) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
        }
    }
    return true;
}

private boolean canAskPermission() {
    return (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP_MR1);
}

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case ALL_PERMISSIONS_RESULT:
            Log.d(TAG, "onRequestPermissionsResult");
            for (String perms : permissionsToRequest) {
                if (!hasPermission(perms)) {
                    permissionsRejected.add(perms);
                }
            }

            if (permissionsRejected.size() > 0) {
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                    if (shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(permissionsRejected.get(0))) {
                        showMessageOKCancel("These permissions are mandatory for the application. Please allow access.",
                                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                                            requestPermissions(permissionsRejected.toArray(
                                                    new String[permissionsRejected.size()]), ALL_PERMISSIONS_RESULT);
                                        }
                                    }
                                });
                        return;
                    }
                }
            } else {
                Log.d(TAG, "No rejected permissions.");
                canGetLocation = true;
                getLocation();
            }
            break;
    }
}

public void showSettingsAlert() {
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    alertDialog.setTitle("GPS is not Enabled!");
    alertDialog.setMessage("Do you want to turn on GPS?");
    alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    alertDialog.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.cancel();
        }
    });

    alertDialog.show();
}

private void showMessageOKCancel(String message, DialogInterface.OnClickListener okListener) {
    new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this)
            .setMessage(message)
            .setPositiveButton("OK", okListener)
            .setNegativeButton("Cancel", null)
            .create()
            .show();
}

public String formatValue(double d){
    String dStr = String.valueOf(d);
    String value = dStr.matches("\\d+\\.\\d*[1-9]\\d*") ? dStr : dStr.substring(0,dStr.indexOf("."));
    return value;
}



private void updateUI(Location loc) {
    Log.d(TAG, "updateUI");
    double latitude = loc.getLatitude();
    double longitude = loc.getLongitude();

    tvLatitude.setText(formatValue(latitude));
    tvLongitude.setText(formatValue(longitude));

}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if (locationManager != null) {
        locationManager.removeUpdates(this);
    }
    android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
    super.onDestroy();
}


}
```

I need two files: **MainActivity.java** and **GPSTracking.java** but I really can't figure out how to split it into those two files. Thanks to all!

Comment: Put all of the location related codes to GPSTracking class. And also define an interface in GPSTracking. This interface must have methods related location events (onLocationChanged e.g) and permissions (mostly you will need). Then implement the interface on MainActivity. The purpose here is to make able to talk MainActivity and GPSTracking.

Comment: what is a purpose to using this:  for (String perm : wanted) {
        if (!hasPermission(perm)) {
            result.add(perm);
        }
    } because according to hasPermission method it will be never false.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new `GpsTracking.java` and implement following interfaces.

```
 1. LocationListener (`import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener`)
 2. GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks
 3. GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener
```

And then use `GoogleApiClient` to do the rest of the job. 
Don't forget to use `LocationManager` and `FusedLocationApi` .

But I would recommend, you should implement it in the same class. Unless you want to reuse it. 
But still, it reduces complexity of the code and algorithms.